# How to instruct haddock to link to hackage documentation for hackage packages?

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock, hackage, cabal-new

So, I am using haddock (through cabal) to generate documentation for my local Haskell package. It has no trouble hyperlinking its own local html documents to each other. However, whenever my package references a symbol from another package, it does not create the link.

Most of my outside dependencies have haddock documentation on Hackage. Is there a way to set up haddock such that it can find the documentation of Hackage and hyperlink to it?

Comment: If you install the package locally with documentation (see `--enable-documentation`. for `cabal`), your local docs will link to the other external packages' local docs. Regarding Hackage: when you upload your package to Hackage, docs linking to other packages on Hackage wwill automatically be created. There is no way to link your local package Hackage docs though.

Comment: @Alec I had issues building the docs for the dependencies. Could I download the ones from hackage instead of trying to build them myself?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can. That seems like a potentially neat feature though, so I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/1086.

Comment: @Alec okay. Also, thank you! I was considering doing that myself, but just wanted to make sure it wasn't already in it.

Comment: @Alec This cabal command seems to say it can work with haddock, but I can't get it to work: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix-local-build.html#cfg-flag---html-location

Answer (score 3):

I usually do,

```
cabal v2-haddock --haddock-html-location='https://hackage.haskell.org/package/$pkg-$version/docs' --haddock-hyperlink-source --haddock-quickjump
```

The only problem for me with this approach is that, it may link with latest packages that are not yet available on Hackage.
For example, when I run this on ghc-8.8 it links to base-4.13 which hasn't been released on Hackage yet.

Comment: When I do this, it tells me it can't find link destinations for each of those external definitions, and doesn't generate hyperlinks. Any guesses?

Comment: @dfeuer It's been a while since I have done this, but I believe you still need documentation built for all the dependencies. So either add `ghc-options: -haddock` to `program-default-options` section of `~/.cabal/config` file or add `documentation: True` for all packages (`package *`) in cabal.project.

Comment: Thanks. These are external dependencies, so not part of my project. Does that mean I'll have to nuke the package database and build docs for *everything*? Or download the source for all those packages and make them part of my project temporarily?

Comment: You likely don't need to delete anything, just adding 
```
package *
   documentation: True
```
in your cabal.project should be enough